# I would like to look at frequency of dates as they appear as days of the week as well as hourly

Tags: r, date, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a dataframe (df) of dates and times which looks as follows (excerpt):

```
date         time
2019-09-01   05:00 PM
2019-09-01   06:10 PM
2019-09-03   04:13 AM
2019-09-05   12:19 AM
2019-09-05   03:02 AM
2019-09-06   09:22 PM
2019-10-01   05:01 PM
2019-10-01   08:34 PM
2019-10-03   01:11 PM
2019-10-05   07:43 AM
2019-10-05   09:29 PM
2019-10-06   05:22 PM
...          ...
```

This is a sample of the data but I have two objectives:

1. Show frequency of observations based on day of the week
2. Show frequency of observations based on time

So for **objective 1** I am able to make a new dataframe of the counts as follows

```
day_groups <- df %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarize(number = n())
```

However I am trying to group by the day of the week the date is and I am unsure how to do this, StackOverflow says lubricate but I'm struggling there.

**Objective 2** has some similarities however there for times. Because times are rarely the same, I cannot 'group_by' time. Instead, the best I could potentially do is the nearest 30 minute interval. If not,the hour will suffice. But basically, I would like to show which blocks of time appear the most, that is how many entries are from 8:00AM -8:30AM, etc.

The goal here is to display the information graphically. 1 of the days of the week which appear the most and 1 that show which time blocks have the most entries (like 30 minute bins).

I think 2 bar graphs would make the most sense here, however any creative suggestions are welcome!

Comment: could you provide a copy&pasteable version of your sample data, using `dput` or `{datapasta}`?

Comment: Take a look at `help("weekdays")` for the first part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1 - Show frequency of observations based on day of the week

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date), 
         wday = weekdays(date)) %>%
  count(wday)

#  wday         n
#  <chr>    <int>
#1 Friday       1
#2 Saturday     2
#3 Sunday       3
#4 Thursday     3
#5 Tuesday      3
```

Part2 - Show frequency of observations based on time

```
df %>%
  mutate(pers = period_to_seconds(hms(format(as.POSIXct(time, 
                format = "%I:%M %p"), "%T"))),
         group = cut(pers, seq(0, 86400, 1800), labels = FALSE)) %>%
  count(group)

#   group     n
#   <int> <int>
# 1     1     1
# 2     7     1
# 3     9     1
# 4    16     1
# 5    27     1
# 6    34     1
# 7    35     2
# 8    37     1
# 9    42     1
#10    43     2
```

Where `group` would have number 1-48 based for each 30 mins of the day.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("2019-09-01", "2019-09-03", "2019-09-05", 
"2019-09-06", "2019-10-01", "2019-10-03", "2019-10-05", "2019-10-06"
), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(4L, 7L, 3L, 12L, 2L, 
10L, 5L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 11L, 6L), .Label = c("01:11 PM", "03:02 AM", 
"04:13 AM", "05:00 PM", "05:01 PM", "05:22 PM", "06:10 PM", "07:43 AM", 
"08:34 PM", "09:22 PM", "09:29 PM", "12:19 AM"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```